# Harmonic Oscillator and Shifts in Derivative Operators

Tags: general-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, operators, symmetry, harmonic-oscillator

What symmetries/symmetry breaking arises from shifts in the derivative operators? To explain what I mean let's study an example.

The classical one particle one dimensional harmonic oscillator has the following Lagrangian
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{L}(x(t),\dot{x}(t)) = \frac{1}{2}\left(\dot{x}(t)\right)^2 - \frac{1}{2}k \left(x(t)\right)^2.\tag{1}
\end{equation}
From the principle of least action, the minimization of the variation of the Lagrangian provides the following equations of motions
\begin{equation}
\ddot{x}(t) + k x(t) = 0.\tag{2}
\end{equation}
Returning to the Lagrangian, the following transformation of the derivative operator turns the Lagrangian of a simple harmonic oscillator into that of the damped (or driven) harmonic oscillator;
\begin{align}
\hat{\mathcal{O}} &=\frac{d}{dt} \to \hat{\mathcal{O}}^\prime = \frac{d}{dt^\prime} = \frac{d}{dt} \pm \gamma = \hat{\mathcal{O}} \pm \gamma\\
\mathcal{L}&\to\mathcal{L}^\prime = \frac{1}{2}\left(\left[\hat{\mathcal{O}}\pm\gamma \right]x(t)\right)^2-\frac{1}{2}k(x(t))^2
\end{align}
Applying the Euler-Lagrange equations for the above Lagrangian one finds
$$\ddot{x}(t)\pm\gamma\dot{x}(t)+kx(t)=0.\tag{3}$$
It seems that shifts in derivative operators generically cause dissipative features.

**Questions:** What physical statements about Noether's theorem can be made?

**Question:** The similarities between shifting derivatives and shifting metrics is fairly striking. Considering changing Minkowski to an arbitrary metric, $g_{ab}$, then you have
$$\eta_{ab}\to g_{ab} \text{ causes } \partial_{a} \to \nabla_a = \partial_a - \Gamma_{ac}^c,$$
where we have employed a coordinate basis. In going from $\eta\to g$ you have lost the Poincare group and one has to often find Killing vectors to recover some symmetries. **Is there a connection between shifting derivatives to go from a conservative to dissipative system and shifting from a flat to a curved spacetime?**